# How to purge *all* Geoclue packages?

Tags: system-installation

Does anyone know how to purge all of geoclue's packages from the system?

Goal is to be geoclue free.

Comment: These well meaning answers ignore the unspoken part of the original question, which is, how do you remove geoclue without also removing gnome and all of gnome's dependencies?  Geoclue, like pulseaudio, also has inverted dependency relationship.  The way it is set, Gnome is dependent upon Geoclue.  "You can't have gnome without this privacy invasive security issue."

Answer (score 8):

Uninstall just geoclue:

```
sudo apt-get remove geoclue
```

(This will remove just the geoclue package itself.)

Uninstall geoclue and it's dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove geoclue
```

(This will remove the geoclue package and any other dependant packages which are no longer needed.)

Purging your config/data too:
(If you also want to delete your local/config files for geoclue then this will work.)

```
sudo apt-get purge geoclue
```

or

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove geoclue
```

http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/vivid/main/g/geoclue/uninstall/index.html

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get purge geoclude && sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

The second command will also remove all the unneeded dependencies leftover from other previous package uninstallations.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge geoclue*
```